# Syntax to parse data and use it to tag it into a new category in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create category of (1) domestic routes **and** (2) international routes for data of flight from one country to another. The difficult part is that often times flights visit more than 1 country.

I imagine I have to parse the data but cannot find the correct syntax to tag the parsed data into these 2 categories.

Example 1:

- Country Origin: **Australia**
- Flight Route: **Australia** - **Australia**
- Expected query result: *Domestic route*

Example 2:

- Country Origin: **Australia**
- Flight Route: **Australia** - Indonesia - Japan
- Expected query result: *International route*

Comment: SO is not a code factory. You need to provide your code, than we can help.

Answer (score 0):

use `string_split()` function which will return the rows based on your separator which is `'-'`, then do `aggregation` based on same values.

```
select top 1 case when ct > 1 then 'local' else 'international' end from (
    select count(1) ct
    from 
    string_split('Australia - Indonesia  - Japan', '-')
    group by rtrim(ltrim(value))) as t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Declare @t table (country nvarchar(150))
Insert into @t values ('Australia - Australia')
Insert into @t values ('Australia - Indonesia - Japan')

select country,case when cnt > 1 then 'International route' else 'Domestic route' END AS 'Flight Route' from (
select *,len(country) - len(replace(country,'-','')) as Cnt from @t
) t
```